# Modify functions in R using body, formals and environment methods

Tags: r, methods, arguments

**function definition**

```
f <- function(x) {
   x + x*x
}
```

3 methods i.e. `body`, `formals` and `environment` can be used for modification

**body**

```
> body(f)
{
    x + x * x
}
```

If we want to change the body using `body`

```
> body(f) <- expression({x*x*x})
> f
function (x) 
{
    x * x * x
}
```

see its changed.

**formals**

If want to change the arguments using `formals` to `(x = 3, y = 6)`

```
> formals(f) <- list(x = 3, y = 4)
> f
function (x = 3, y = 4) 
{
    x * x * x
}
```

see its changed.

But if want to change the arguments to `(x, y)` instead. Obviously `formals(f) <- list(x, y)` will not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `alist`:

```
formals(f) = alist(x =, y =)
```

`alist` constructs a list from its unevaluated arguments.

Comment: For some reason my previous comment was removed but I would *actually be interested* if somebody could point me to errors/omissions in my answer.